# openssl encrpyt java decrypt

Tags: java, openssl, aes, public-key-encryption

Hello I am using openssl to encrypt a string and JAVA code to decrypt it. My `key` is "SUDIPTA123". The command I am using to encrypt

```
encdata=$(echo -n "12345627678" | openssl enc -v -aes-256-cbc -base64 -nosalt -pass "pass:$key")
```

`encdata` contains `/oUakLZnim7aPtpRySLRDw==`.

Now I am using the follwoing JAVA code to decrypt `encdata`

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AESDecryptor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String encryptedText = "/oUakLZnim7aPtpRySLRDw==";
        String password = "SUDIPTA123";

        try {
            byte[] encryptedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText);
            byte[] ivBytes = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 0, ivBytes, 0, 16);
            byte[] encryptedData = new byte[encryptedBytes.length - 16];
            System.arraycopy(encryptedBytes, 16, encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.length);
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), ivBytes, 65536, 256);
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new 
            SecretKeySpec(factory.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes));

            byte[] decryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);

            String decryptedText = new String(decryptedData, "UTF-8");
            System.out.println("Decrypted Text: " + decryptedText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After running the code `decryptedText` is empty string. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Decryption fails because OpenSSL statement and Java code apply different key derivation functions (KDFs): In the OpenSSL statement the default `EVP_BytesToKey()` is used, in the Java code PBKDF2.
In order for both codes to be compatible, the *same* KDF must be applied, i.e. if the OpenSSL statement is the reference, `EVP_BytesToKey()` must be used in the Java code.
There are various Java implementations on the web for `EVP_BytesToKey()`, e.g. the one from BouncyCastle.
Your decryption works if you replace the key and IV derivation part in your Java code, i.e. the complete first block inside the `try {}`, with (using BouncyCastle):

```java
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.digests.SHA256Digest;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.generators.OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
...
byte[] encryptedData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedText); // no separation required (since OpenSSL does not concatenate IV and cipertext)
byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator pbeGenerator = new OpenSSLPBEParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest()); // SHA256 as of v1.1.0 (if in OpenSSL the default digest is applied)
pbeGenerator.init(passwordBytes, new byte[0]); // no salt (as you did not apply a salt in the OpenSSL statement)
ParametersWithIV parameters = (ParametersWithIV) pbeGenerator.generateDerivedParameters(256, 128); // 32 bytes key, 16 bytes IV
KeyParameter keyParam = (KeyParameter)parameters.getParameters();
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyParam.getKey(), "AES");
byte[] ivBytes = parameters.getIV();
...
```

---

Security:

- `EVP_BytesToKey()` is deprecated (since insecure) and should no longer be used. Reliable key derivation functions are Argon2 or at least PBKDF2. The latter is also supported by more modern OpenSSL versions (via the *-pbkdf2* and *-iter* options).
  In the context of PBKDF2, use an iteration count that is as large as possible with acceptable performance (usually a few 100000).
- A key derivation without salt is insecure. To use a salt in your OpenSSL statement, remove the *-nosalt* option. Then, your OpenSSL statement returns the Base64 encoding of the ASCII encoding of `Salted__`, followed by an 8 bytes salt and the actual ciphertext.
  The salt and ciphertext must be separated during decryption. Afterwards, key and IV can be derived with passphrase and salt, and finally the actual ciphertext can be decrypted with the derived key and IV.